# Copy string to clipboard using Selection.Copy not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is the code that I managed to assemble through the help of the kind people here:

```
Sub GetFullPath()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim PicPath As String

    PicPath = Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    PicPath = Selection.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName

    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    Selection.InsertAfter vbCr & "<img src=" & Chr(34) & PicPath & Chr(34) & ">"

    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    
End Sub
```

Is there a way to copy the string following .InsertAfter vbCr to the clipboard? I've tried using Selection.Copy but it copies the picture instead of the string.

Comment: `Selection.Copy` copies the cell or range of cells selected in the worksheet. You have no selection in the worksheet, and the part after `.InsertAfter` is code, not cell content. There's no way to copy code directly to the clipboard. You can put `PicPath` into a cell and then copy that cell's content into the clipboard.